# How to create ObjectID from its string representation [pyarrow]

Tags: python, pyarrow

I am saving a Python object to the Plasma store in one client, and want to load it in another.  My idea was to pass the ObjectID as part of an HTTP request.  So I have something like:

```
import pyarrow.plasma as plasma

client = plasma.connect("/tmp/plasma")
payload = {"a": 1}
object_id = client.put(payload)
object_str = str(object_id)
print(object_str)  # outputs: "ObjectID(8d8e54e5cb547962a6d16ff2869c2c3282ff6550)"
```

In my destination client, I expected that I would be able to do something like:

```
import pyarrow.plasma as plasma
client = plasma.connect("/tmp/plasma")

data = client.get("8d8e54e5cb547962a6d16ff2869c2c3282ff6550")
```

But this doesn't work, as `client.get` is expecting a `plasma.ObjectID` object, not a string identifier.  But then I cannot find any way to create an `plasma.ObjectID` object using this identifier.  It says I need to pass in 20-bytes, but I'm not sure how to get the right 20 bytes from this ID.  I have tried things like `plasma.ObjectID(b'8d8e54e5cb547962a6d16ff2869c2c3282ff6550')` to no avail.

The only thing I've found that works is a hacky solution of listing all the objects in the store like "client.list()", and then string-matching the string representation of the ObjectID keys in the returned dictionary.

If I'm not following the intended design, how do I:

1. save a python object to Plasma in server 1
2. pass a reference over HTTP from one server to another
3. access this object in server 2?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.  The printed ObjectID is a hexcode.  You can convert it to bytes like this:

```
# source
import pyarrow.plasma as plasma
client = plasma.connect("/tmp/plasma")

payload = {"a": 1}
object_id = client.put(payload)
object_str = str(object_id)
print(object_str)  # outputs: "ObjectID(8d8e54e5cb547962a6d16ff2869c2c3282ff6550)"

# client
id_str = "8d8e54e5cb547962a6d16ff2869c2c3282ff6550"
object = plasma.ObjectID(bytes.fromhex(id_str))
data = client.get(object)
```